# The given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to type varbinary of the specified target column

Tags: c#, sqlbulkcopy

I have a datatable with one column which has image file path. I need to replace the file path with byte array of that image. The below code gives me error.

> The given value of type String from the data source cannot be
>   converted to type varbinary of the specified target column.

```
for (int rowIncrement = 0; rowIncrement < dt.Rows.Count; rowIncrement++)
{
    byte[] photo = GetPhoto(dt.Rows[rowIncrement]["image"]);
    dt.Rows[rowIncrement]["image"] = photo;
    dt.AcceptChanges();
}
using (SqlBulkCopy copy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlCon, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepNulls | SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity, null))
{
    copy.DestinationTableName = "UserDetails";
    copy.WriteToServer(dt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The column type should be specified otherwise the columns value is still a string when you need a byte[]

Example:

```
// ADD a new column since you cannot change the type

dt.Columns.Add("image_tmp", typeof (byte[]));

for (int rowIncrement = 0; rowIncrement < dt.Rows.Count; rowIncrement++)
{
    byte[] photo = GetPhoto(dt.Rows[rowIncrement]["image"]);
    dt.Rows[rowIncrement]["image_tmp"] = photo;
    dt.AcceptChanges();
}

// REMOVE image column and rename the temporary column
dt.Columns.Remove("image");
dt.Columns["image_tmp"].ColumnName = "image";
```